# Updating value of variable based on value of HTML input

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTML input that accepts only numbers and on my script file I have I variable that gets the value of the input. What I want to do is create another variable that is equal to the first variable. When I put a number on the input field the value of the `numInput` variable changes but not on the
`value` variable. 
**EDIT**
what I am trying to do is, I want to use the value of the `value` variable on some functions that I will make.

```js
const numInput = document.getElementById("input");
const value = numInput.value;
```

```html
<header> 
   <input type="number" name="numInput" id="input" class="input" min="0" value="1" required>
</header>
```

Comment: Use `.valueAsNumber` instead of `.value` for `<input type="number">`. Other than that, yes, values don’t change by themselves. Use ``numInput.addEventListener("input", ({ valueAsNumber: value }) => { /* Use `value` here. */ });`` or something similar. What specifically are you trying to do with `value` and when? Please [edit] and clarify.

Comment: Thanks @SebastianSimon I've edit the question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JS objects are the only things in JS that are not cloned in assignment to a new variable. This includes arrays.

Therefore, to mimic the behaviour, you will need to update your value upon every change, typically by adding an event listener. I've chosen to use the `change` event which will only fire upon blur if the value has changed of fields involving the keyboard and selection/alteration of range/date if the value has changed, though you could use the `input` event if you want it to change on every keypress, too. Have a quick read:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event

When doing this, the `value` can't be a constant, either, as it will change, so it must be a variable instead. I've opted for a `let` declaration for better code isolation, but by all means use `var` if you need more flexibility.

```js
const numInput = document.getElementById("input");
let value = numInput.value;

numInput.addEventListener('change', () => {
    value = numInput.value;
});
```

Comment: FYI a constant is not a type of variable. They are by definition either constant (`const`) or varadic, alterable, changeable (`var`, `let`). This is especially important for anyone considering altering my answer.

Comment: Thanks I was able to solve the problem using this solution.

Comment: Consider the upvote too, @RDovez

Answer (score 2):

The reason `value` does not change is because it is saving a copy of the `numInput.value` content during the assignment, not a pointer or reference (something that I don't think you could do on JS). I would suggest using just using `.valueAsNumber` as suggested by @Sebastian Simon.

Comment: `valueAsNumber` has nearly nothing to do with security; it’s just for convenience and it’s the reason why `<input type="number">` is useful in the first place.

Comment: Oh, I though it was to protect against XSS. I imagined you were trying to sanitize the input. Updating...

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish this, JavaScript needs to trigger a function when the input value of the HTML element has been changed. To do so, an event listener is needed.

Try changing the input value so you can see the code in action:

```js
document.getElementById("input").addEventListener('input', function(){
    let inputNumber = this.value
    console.log('your variable value is: ' + inputNumber)
})
```

```html
<header> 
   <input type="number" name="numInput" id="input" class="input" min="0" value="1" required>
</header>
```

Comment: Your code prevents the use of `inputNumber` outside of your listener, which might well be something the OP desired.

Comment: Also, if you're worried about variables or constants being named the same as properties on objects, you're going to be in for a tough time coding, though it is usually a good idea to avoid non-descriptive variable/constant names.

Comment: @SEoF Are these suggestions meant to improve the answer or my coding skills in some way? .. I really don't see how that would be the case. By the way, to refresh your memory, SO is not a platform to code for others.

Comment: They've mentioned they want a variable to change value opon the value of an input changing. Your code doesn't change the value of a variable, but instead creates a new variable and then destroys it. Ergo, your solution doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Regarding your second point, I've provided links to the spec and have detailed why I've changed things the way I have. This all helps in an educational stand point. Unlike yourself, I haven't suggested avoiding certain variable names which is very subjective and not part of providing a solution or answer.

Comment: Also, regarding SO, you're supposed to discuss how someones answer needs to change before changing it, as this way you avoid changing someones answer into being incorrect. Sure, if they don't make ammends accordingly and don't discuss the problems with the suggestions, then make the changes, but don't just change it.